# Pick properties from nested type object without key [key: string]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Hi I am in a situation where I need to pick a properties of a nested object and that object doesn't have a key name (its [key: string]). Is there a way where I can create a type by using the Pick utility type

```
type SomeData = {
  streaming: {
    [key: string]: {
      id: number;
      title: string;
      live: string;
       ....
    };
  };
};
```

I just need to pick the `title` and `live` from `SomeData`, so I did

```
type myType = Pick<SomeData, 'streaming[key].title'>;
or 
type myType = Pick<SomeData['streaming'], keyof liveHighlightsData['streaming']>;
```

but this obviously isn't complete though.
thanks

Comment: What is the resullting type supposed to be?

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing `Pick` for something else. I'm pretty sure you're just after `SomeData["streaming"][string]`.

Comment: If you really want to have a nested pick, that would allow you to pick deep properties, consider looking at [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAxVZN). If it works for you, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This does it

```
type myType = {
  [key: string]: Pick<
    SomeData['streaming'][string],
    'title' | 'live'
  >;
};
```